# Is there an algorithm for "contextual recognition" with probabilities?

Tags: classification, algorithm, probability

**Example 1**

An object is composed of 3 sub-objects.

- Object 1: 90% looks like an eye 10% looks like a wheel
- Object 2: 50% looks like an eye 50% looks like a wheel
- Object 3: 90% looks like a mouth 10% looks like a roof

OK. So now we want to determine what the whole-object is. Using this evidence maybe we find:

- Combined Object: 90% looks like a face 10% looks like an upside-down car.

But now, *given this*, we go back an reclassify the sub-objects.

- Given whole object is a car object 2 is 99% an eye.

I'm looking for an algorithm that sort of goes back and forth between the context and the subobjects to classify both an object and it's parts.

(This is related to the rabbit-duck illusion, where such an algorithm once decided something is a rabbit, it classifies it's parts as rabbit-parts).

In other words the algorithm needs to calculate conditional probabilities P(A|B) but the B depends on what all the A's are! So it's a feed back loop.

**Example 2**
There is a word "funny". The sub-letters are classified (wrongly) as F U M Y. It guesses that the word is FUNNY and then goes back and tries to reclassify the letters. Using this reclassification it is even more certain the word is FUNNY. And much more certain the letters in the middle are NN and not M.
(Perhaps later the word is used in a sentence "The fumes from this fire are really fumy". And then using this new evidence it has to go back and reclassify the word again and now it thinks the word is FUMY with 80% probability).

I have an idea that I would write all the condition probabilities in a matrix $M$ then gives starting probabilities $S_0$. Then iterate like this: $S_{n+1}=M S_n$ until hopefully it converges on something.